# why ansible_facts['distribution']=="Suse" skipping apache install on Suse

Tags: ansible-playbook

I created the simple ansible playbook to install apache on CentOS and Suse.   It works on CentOS but skipping on Suse without any errors, I do not understand why.

This is the playbook:

- name: To install Apache on CentOS and Suse
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: True
  become: yes
  become_user: root

```
tasks:
  - name: Installing Apache on CentOS or RedHat
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
    when: ansible_facts['distribution']=="CentOS" or ansible_facts['distribution']=="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"

  - name: Installing Apache on Suse
    zypper:
      name: apache2
      state: latest
    when: ansible_facts['distribution']=="Suse" or ansible_facts['distribution']=="SLES"
```

Comment: use the [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) module and check the actual value of `ansible_facts['distribution']`.

Comment: I added:  register and debug for both  and then for both I got:   VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

Comment: There is your answer why it's not working. Inspect `ansible_facts` and find an attribute that exists.

Comment: ok, thank you that works